# Passing Integer from Fragment to Fragment - sectionsPageAdapter, ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, integer, android-viewpager, fragment

What I am trying to do:

I have an activity that hosts two fragments - CreateActivity.java that hosts Fragment1.java and Fragment2.java.

When an item in ListFragment is clicked in Fragment1, I want to switch to view Fragment2 and display some information based on the position clicked in the list in Fragment1.

I am trying to pass the "position" value of the list like so:

User Clicks on ListFragment item in Fragment1, this code then sends the value of "position" to the CreateActivity.java:

```
OnMemeSelectedListener mCallback;

public interface OnListSelectedListener {
    public void onArticleSelected(int position);
}

public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallback = (OnListSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);
}
```

In CreateActivity.java the following method is called to obtain the integer "position":

```
    @Override
public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
    // Fragment2 newFragment = new Fragment2();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(Fragment2.ARG_POSITION, position);
    Fragment2 fragobj = new Fragment2();
    fragobj.setArguments(args);
    Log.w("myApp", "" + position);
    //Switch to Fragment2 Tab
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```

Up till here it is full working as the log outputs the correct list of the position. Now to obtain the integer in Fragment2.class I write the following line:

```
int Position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
```

However I get an NullPointError in my log upon starting CreateActivity.java:

```
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at com.meme.hdmeme.Fragment2.onCreateView(Fragment2.java:59)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2313)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
08-31 17:45:04.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14779):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Ive been stuck on this for hours and cant find a way round at all, line 59 (causing the NPE) is:

```
int Position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
```

Do I have to set the arguments of Fragment2 before it is created? I want to pass this data to Fragment2 after it has been created within the activity, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you are calling `getArguments()` in your `onCreateView`. At that point there are no arguments to get yet.

Override `setArguments` in your Fragment2 and put the relevant code that displays the stuff you get from the first Fragment in there.

This has to go into your Fragment2:

```
 @Override
    public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
        super.setArguments(args);
        int Position = args.getInt(ARG_POSITION, position);

        // now adjust what ever you want to display
    }
```

Comment: By this do you  mean create a method in Fragment 2 (outside onCreateview) that calls setArguments()? Apologies I am still really new at coding

Comment: One more small thing, I have an imageView inside my onCreateView that I want to change the image of depending on the value "position" I have tried changing it within the setArguments method but keep getting a nullpointerror, is it possible to pass int position to the onCreateView?

Comment: onCreateView happens before you set the arguments. In setArguments try ImageView v = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.myimageview); v.setImageResource(R.drawable.myprettypicture);

Comment: Hmm this is what I initially tried, however I keep getting nullpointerror caused by the line ImageView v = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.myimageview). Which I cannot figure out why

Comment: Have a look at the example here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Example They are using onCreateView for retrevinng the arguments. (Have a look at the DetaiFragment code in particular.)

Comment: I had a look at the example but I can't see how its relevant, the index is input as an argument (which is what we have managed to do) but its not used within the fragment from thereon?

Comment: it is:  text.setText(Shakespeare.DIALOGUE[getShownIndex()]); that looks up the arguments...

Comment: Having a look at the example, I still cannot seem to figure it out (for two days now :( ). getShownIndex refers to retrieving an integer by setting arguments, from a new instance. However when I go to create a new instance of Fragment2 from Fragment1, I get "the method newInstance() is not defined for the type Fragment...."

Comment: I think its because in my case, onCreateView being run as soon as the activity is being created, so in this case (before I have clicked the listview in fragment1) getShownIndex has no value...npe